# How to associate data from two different surveys coming from two different populations?

Tags: regression, correlation, survey, population

I want to associate between staff perception of hospital quality with patient satisfaction about hospital services quality. Two different surveys were used for the 2 different population. The only common thing is that they were collected from the same hospitals. 
Other meaning: How to find the relation (correlation or regression) between the independent variable (Six Sigma methodology: from the first survey) and between the dependent variable (patient satisfaction: from the second survey)? 
I have two study populations: the first is the in-patient client at the Hospital and the second population is health providers at the same

the first survey was to collect the data from workers (health providers: 328 persons) aiming to measure the level of using Six Sigma methodology at the hospitals. The survey consisted of (5) domains (DMAIC) that is (define, measure, analyze, improve, control) and total of (68) statements by Likert scale (5 degrees: strongly agree, agree, neutral, disagree, strongly disagree).

the second survey was to collect the data from in-patients client (540 patients) aiming to measure the level of patient satisfaction at the hospitals. The survey consisted of (5) domains (DMAIC) that is (define, measure, analyze, improve, control) and total of (36) statements by Likert scale (5 degrees: strongly agree, agree, neutral, disagree, strongly disagree).

Actually, I collected the data from the two populations, but I don't know how to correlate between them as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Quick question: were these surveys with validation?  Or were they surveys that you made. If the first, then you have less work, if the second, then you have more work. There are a couple of ways to do what you want to do. It depends on who your audience is (what I mean by that is more complex methods might be inappropriate if your audience is the board of directors at the hospital).

Comment: The both patients and workers from the same hospital and at the same period of time. About the workers, they are all of the health providers with an administrative or supervision tasks (i.e. physician, nurse, pharmacologist, radiologist, management board, ...), and they are about (14.8%) of total workers in the hospital. That's meaning there is other workers not included, they are without supervision tasks.